# Removing enclosed text in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I would like to delete *enclosed text* between special characters like: ["{'<( etc .. this way I can remove text like "this is a very ... long text" with a simple keyboard shortcut. I was looking for some already existing mode that performs something similar but I didn't found any so I created some lisp code which performs good in most of situations, however it's not working correctly in all cases. For example if I have the following text entry and I put the cursor in the position"^" then I would liek to remove all the text enclosed by " but it doesn't work:

"aaaaa ] > [more text] aaaaa"
------------             ^

My lisp code is the following:

```
;; returns the enclosing character for the character "c"
(defun get-enc-char (c) (cond
                         ((string= c "(") ")")
                         ((string= c "[") "]")
                         ((string= c "{") "}")
                         ((string= c ">") "<")
                         ((string= c "<") ">")
                         ((string= c "'") "'")
                         ((string= c "\"") "\"")
                         (t nil)
                         )
  )

(defun delete-enclosed-text ()
  "Delete texts between any pair of delimiters."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (let (p1 p2 mychar)
      ; look for one of those characters and store the cursor position
      (skip-chars-backward "^([\'\"><{") (setq p1 (point))
      ; store the char at this point, look for its enclosed char and advance
      ; the cursor newly (this done to avoid the cases when the char and
      ; its enclosed-char are the same like " or ' chars.
      (backward-char 1) (setq mychar (thing-at-point 'char)) (forward-char 1)
      ; look forward for the enclosed char
      (skip-chars-forward (concatenate 'string "^" (get-enc-char mychar))) (setq p2 (point))
      ; only delete the region if we found the enclosed character
      (if (looking-at "[\]\}\"\'\)<>]") (kill-region p1 p2)))))
```

Following is an example: [image]

Comment: It seems to be because you're looking for all bracket types instead of the specific type that is enclosing the particular region you're trying to delete.  So when you have a angle bracket in a double quoted string, it gets confused.  Try to determine the bracket type and only look for those.

Comment: FWIW, I generally use the `expand-region` package to select (and maybe delete) regions like this.  But it certainly takes more keystrokes.

Comment: Which region should be removed if point was at `^`? in this example:
`aa < bb " cc ^ dd > ee "`?

Comment: @Thomas in general the case your put as example I think is not usual in most programming languages but it could happen in some strange scenario. My idea is to remove text between two special characters like function arguments, text content, html elements, tags etc. So in the case of you example I don't know how should we proceed. Maybe either cases (removing text between " or <) would be OK.

Comment: @sds basically nothing happens. The text is not removed correctly.

Comment: I don't know what exactly the result you want, like whether the quote mark need to be removed. However, it can be simply achieved by `forward-sexp` or `mark-sexp`. Have a look on these functions and all those `sexp` related.

Comment: Please try to specify the behavior you want more precisely (clearly). Maybe even say what you're really trying to do (e.g. why you want to do what you think you want to do). That will perhaps help people help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution based on your code

```el
;; returns the enclosing character for the character "c"
  (defun get-enc-char (c) (cond
                           ((string= c "(") ")")
                           ((string= c "[") "]")
                           ((string= c "{") "}")
                           ((string= c ">") "<")
                           ((string= c "<") ">")
                           ((string= c "'") "'")
                           ((string= c "\"") "\"")
                           (t nil)
                           ))
 (defvar empty-enclose 0)
  (defun delete-enclosed-text ()
    "Delete texts between any pair of delimiters."
    (interactive)
    (setq empty-enclose 0)
    (save-excursion
      (let (p1 p2 orig)
        (setq orig (point))
        (setq p1 (point))
        (setq p2 (point))
        (setq find 0)
        (setq mychar (thing-at-point 'char))
        (if (-contains? '("(" "[" "{" "<" "'" "\"") mychar)
            (progn
              (setq left_encloser (thing-at-point 'char))
              (backward-char -1)
              (if (string-equal (thing-at-point 'char) (get-enc-char left_encloser))
                  (progn
                    (backward-char -1)
                    (setq p2 (point))
                    (setq find 1)
                    (setq empty-enclose 1)))))
        (while (eq find 0)
          (skip-chars-backward "^({[<>\"'")
          (setq p1 (point))
          (backward-char 1)
          (setq left_encloser (thing-at-point 'char))
          (goto-char orig)
          (while (and (not (eobp)) (eq find 0))
            (backward-char -1)
            (skip-chars-forward "^)}]<>\"'")
            (setq right_encloser (thing-at-point 'char))
            (if (string-equal right_encloser (get-enc-char left_encloser))
                (progn
                  (setq p2 (point))
                  (setq find 1))))
          (goto-char p1)
          (backward-char 1))
        (delete-region p1 p2)))
    (if (eq empty-enclose 0)
        (backward-char 1)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. It works correctly but it fails when I put the cursor at the first character between the delimiters. For example if I put the cursor under the character 1 in the following text the deleting doesn't work: "12222222222"

Comment: @redobot Thank you for testing. I tried another solution. seems better.

Comment: works like a charm :) .. thank you very much. Please, edit the answer to keep only the working version of the code. I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I rapid-sketched something, it doesn't match exactly what you're asking for but I think it could fullfill the same requirements in an even more comfortable way, give it a try and let me know! This interactive function is called **with no arguments after selecting a region** and asks you for an enclosing mark: this can be any char or string that is **directly recognized** by `replace-regex` (direct use of `*`,`.`,`[` etc wouldn't be the case, but you still can use other chars like `{}`,`%` etc or even HTML-like markups like `<idx>`).

The function will delete all text within the selected region, **from the very first apparition of the mark to the very last** (even if there is an odd number of them), marks are also deleted.

```
(defun remove-enclosed-in-selection (beginning end)
"select a region, call this function and type any valid regex
 markup. All characters from its first to its last appearance will
 be removed (including the symbol itself. Example: try with § and %:
 aaaa§bbbbcc%c§cc§ddddeeee§ffffgggghhhhiiii§jjjj§kkkkllll§mmmm%nnnn"
(interactive "r")
(let ((x (read-string "type enclosing mark: ")))
  (narrow-to-region beginning end)
  (replace-regexp (concat x ".*" x) "")
  (widen)))
```

Then you can globally bind it to any keyboard shortcut you want as usual:

`(global-set-key (kbd "C-. <C-return>") 'remove-enclosed-in-selection)`

or locally to any custom hook you may have:

```
(defun custom-whatever-hook ()
  (local-set-key (kbd "C-. <C-return>")) 'remove-enclosed-in-selection)
(add-hook 'whatever-hook 'custom-whatever-hook)
```

so, summarizing:

1. select region
2. `M-x remove-enclosed-in-selection` or your custom keystroke
3. press `RET`, type valid marker, press `RET`
4. the enclosed contents should be removed

The narrow-widen approach seems quick&dirty to me, but I couldn't find another way in the short term. So it may still need a couple of fixes, let me know if it works as expected. Plus, I'm not that an emacs hacker... yet! :P
cheers

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and for the code. But I think this behavior is not what I'm looking for. I need something to delete the text using the minimum number of key-strokes and without the need of introducing any hints. That's it should be clever enough to find the enclosing character and use it as delimiter. I modified the question to add a gif with the desired behavior as you can see my current code is more or less working but there're still some situations when it doesn't.